# Titanium Developer for iPhone

Tags: iphone, appcelerator

Am looking into developing an iPhone native app using [Titanium Developer](http://www.appcelerator.com/)

Since this is still in beta, I am wondering if there are any better options and/or if its a good idea using such software to develop native apps (which are not games; not graphic intensive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to wait, you can do what a lot of us did: develop apps in Cocoa Touch.  It works perfectly well for games as well as non-graphic intensive apps.

Answer (score 0):

The similar and more mature [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com) framework has been used in a number of iPhone apps and Apple only seems to object if the application autoupdates.

That being said, I wouldn't recommend using web frameworks unless your application is really simple--you will get a much better experience from a native application (on both Android and iPhone)

Answer (score 0):

My company uses Titanium and it's working fine so far. It's also a pleasure to develop iPhone app using javascript and co. I'd recomend you give it a try, it's really simple to set up and start coding.

Some reading up: http://boldr.net/iphone-app-with-titanium-mobile/